# WebRTC. The video does not show in <video> tag

Tags: video, webrtc, videochat

I have tag  in "index.html" and a code in the  tag in it. But I can not get a stream/video of my camera. Where I make a mistake?

```
window.onload = function () {
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true}, getStream, noStream);
    };

    function getStream(stream){
        var url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.src = url;
    }

    function noStream(faild){

    }
```

Comment: *** I have <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" width="300"></video> tag in "index.html"  ***

Comment: I wonder what `faild` says?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding log to `noStream` to see if any error

```
function noStream(faild){
  console.log(faild);
}
```

You're actually trying an outdated API but should still work with deprecated warning.

Try this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sasivarunan/2xLbv7n9/) to refer current getUserMedia() API

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myVideo = document.createElement('video');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
}).then(stream => {
    myVideo.srcObject = stream;
    myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        myVideo.play();
        //myVideo.muted = true;
    })
})
```